# In a distribution what do I call regions with high probability mass, that contain smaller peaks within them?

Tags: probability, distributions, terminology

Suppose I have some **multimodal** distribution  as shown below.
It has two regions of high probability, highlighted in purple.
And within those regions are smaller peaks, highlighted in green.

Is there a word for the purple highlighted regions,
and for the green highlighted regions?

What is a good way to describe that we have say 2 big peaks,
with little peaks within them?

[image: sketch of distribution]

Comment: I would be very suspicious that such structure is even genuine unless you (a) have a very large sample size (b) shown that it is repeatable over various histogram choices (bin origin, bin width) or density estimation choices (kernel type and width) (c) have independent substantive reasons for expecting it. That said, I have found *fine structure* a useful generic or catch-all term for details that aren't noise and allow some story (e.g. preferences for particular ages in studies of human populations). In your case a diagram is much more expressive than any word account.

Comment: I want this for metaphor. In my particular case it is a theoretical (or even thought experimental) domain: "the space of ideas/meanings", when someone says a word you can't be sure what it means. Most words are homonyms with different senses, which correspond to the purple areas, and are further distinguished into with polysemes corresponding to green areas. Because some's exact meaning is unique to them and the circumstances they are likely to be a bit off to the side of any given population average peak. And of course there is a nonzero change they may just be using the word incorrectly.

Comment: I doubt that there's statistical terminology to help you. I'd adapt or coin some term, using whatever terminology is to hand from philosophy of language or linguistics.